# Why is scaling affecting my bevel?

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

I want to make my object smaller, but I want to keep exact same bevel (the one on the first picture).
When I make my object smaller, it is also affecting my bevel shape (see the second picture).

How can I make my object smaller, but keep the same rounded bevel shape?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Okay, so I tried again. Created a new object. Really making sure I applied scale before the bevel. Made sure X, Y, Z are all 1. Then I go to rescale it on the Y-axes and I still have the same problem.

Or is the problem that I select everything and then scale it along the Y-axes?

Comment: Sorry my first answer was for using the _Bevel_ modifier, not the _Bevel_ tool in _Edit Mode_. I've made a new answer for this case, I'll leave the other for people with similar problems.

Comment: Oh, stupid question maybe: when you say "Then I go to rescale it on the Y-axes", you do this in _Edit Mode_ or _Object Mode_?

Answer (score 0):

**//EDIT #2:** Forget this answer. This helps people using the *Bevel* modifier so I'll leave it here, but I should have read the question more carefully... you are beveling in *Edit Mode*, it seems.

Beveling dimensions are in relation to the original underlying mesh size. If you scale an object in *Object Mode* instead of *Edit Mode*, it is scaling the object to make the mesh appear in a different size, to say it simplified - the mesh stays the same size, it only appears smaller.

So you either have to scale the mesh in *Edit Mode* to change its original size, or in *Object Mode* you have to apply the scale after changing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale* to make the scaled dimension the original mesh dimension.

**//EDIT:** Just to make something clear which came up in the comments. Applying the scale makes the original mesh size larger (or smaller) and hence the bevel amount might now give different results as it is not automatically changed according to the applied scale.

Therefore it is always best to first apply a scale and then set the bevel amount to the desired size. And although applying the scale at first might seem to "destroy" the bevel, it is important to get evenly sized bevel amount in all directions, because unevenly scaled individual dimensions might make the bevel look distorted in certain directions.

The other way would be to first apply the *Bevel* modifier and then apply the scale. However this makes the change in mesh permanent and you can no longer tweak the bevel settings.

Comment: Thank you for that! However, I already tried revising along Y-axes and then Apply > Scale. This doesn't make a difference. The bevel is still changing. Scaling in Edit Mode also gives me that change in bevel size.

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: @DPlayground Well, the problem is, let's say a cube edge is 2 m and you scale by 2, then it looks like 4 m. The bevel creates a half circle with a size of 1 m, because 1 m from one side and 1 m from the other is the (mesh) dimension of 2 m - since the modifier ignores the scaled 4 m. If you now apply the scale, the modifier doesn't get resized. It's still 1 m from both sides, but the mesh is now 4 m instead of 2 m. The modifier won't get the scale applied. So it is always best to apply the scale **before** using modifiers.

Comment: @DPlayground The other thing is, and that's what I saw in your screenshot, is when an object is scaled different on the individual axes. Let's say its scale on X is 1, but on Y it is 2. Then a bevel of 1 m will be 1 m in X direction but 2 m in Y direction.. so although the bevel is set to 1 m for all axes, it doesn't look even sized in both dimensions - and this is caused by the uneven scaling. So applying the scale is important to get the bevel evenly spaced, ut it'S not automatically fixing the change in dimensions which might make the bevel appear larger or smaller after applying the scale.

Comment: @JohnEason No need for the file, this is exactly as it is expected to work. I edited in as to why this is so.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes. That's clearer now! :^)

Answer (score 0):

If you've made sure that the scale is applied before beveling and you still get an uneven beveling amount, take a look if following settings are used for the *Bevel* tool:

When the *Width Type* of the *Bevel* tool is set to *Offset* (which is the default) or maybe *Width*, *Depth* or *Absolute* it should most likely be correct and evenly spaced in X and Y direction:

[image: bevel offset]

However, when the *Width Type* is set to *Percent*, then the amount of bevel is relative to the length of the edge along which it is beveling. So in the image below it is set to 50%, and 50% of the edge in X direction is much less in absolute meters than 50% of the edge in Y direction:

[image: beveling in percent]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the screenshots! But the problem happens after I already used the bevel. So yes I am indeed bevelling in Edit mode, so I just used Ctrl+B. Then after a while I realised I wanted to make the object smaller on the Y-axes. Since I already beveled I cannot change that bevel. So applying the bevel itself is not the problem. It shows up how I want it, but when I want to rescale my object it changes. So basically I want to make my object smaller in one direction AFTER bevelling it in Edit mode with Ctrl+B. So how do I do that without the bevel changing shape?

Comment: @DPlayground Oh my, now I understand - sorry it took a while. You have beveled the mesh - not procedural with a modifier, but in _Edit Mode_, as we say with a destructive method (meaning you have permanently changed the mesh). And then you want to scale it afterwards... well, that's why people use modifiers. If you first fix the bevel in the mesh and then scale it unevenly on certain axes, then the bevel gets distorted with it as this is now the fixed mesh which you stretch. Never bevel anything in _Edit Mode_ unless you know this is how you want to keep it.

Comment: @DPlayground  Now the only thing you can do this select the beveled part and move it on the Y axis with G until it is the size you want it.

Comment: Ah clear, so its a very permanent method. So then my next question would be, if I use the Bevel Modifier instead, how can I use that on only those two selected edge? Is that possible?

Comment: Actually this site is for answering one question at a time ;) Especially if it would require more elaborate answers it's best to split it up in several questions on different topics. But yes, it's possible with "bevel weights" as a quick tip on what to search for.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much for your help!